# Cannot get SQLI to INSERT null if no $_POST value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've tried multiple ways to try and to get this to work. Have tried all the ways answered on previous questions on this topic and cannot get it.

I am trying to insert *NULL* instead of the string NULL into the database if the $_POST variable has no value. It just keeps inserting the string 'NULL' or just a blank column. Here are all the ways I have tried the query.

My Database class has a method `sql_prep` :

```
public function sql_prep($postVariable){
  $output;
  if(trim($postVariable) == ''){
    $output = 'NULL';
  }else{
  $output = strval(mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $postVariable));
  };
  return $output;
}
```

Here is the query:

```
 if(isset($_POST["createUserSubmit"])) : 
  $temp_connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
  $firstName = $db->sql_prep($_POST["firstName"]);
  $lastName = $db->sql_prep($_POST["lastName"]);
  $companyName = $db->sql_prep($_POST["companyName"]);
  $streetAddress = $db->sql_prep($_POST["streetAddress"]);
  $streetAddress2 = $db->sql_prep($_POST["streetAddress2"]);
  $streetAddress3 = $db->sql_prep($_POST["streetAddress3"]);
  $city = $db->sql_prep($_POST["city"]);
  $state = $db->sql_prep($_POST["state"]);
  $zip = $db->sql_prep($_POST["zipCode"]);
  $country = $db->sql_prep($_POST["country"]);
  $phone = $db->sql_prep($_POST["phone"]);
  $fax = $db->sql_prep($_POST["fax"]);
  $email = $db->sql_prep($_POST["email"]);
  mysqli_query($temp_connection, "INSERT INTO Address(firstName, lastName, companyName, address1, address2, address3, city, state, zip, country, phone, fax, email, dateCreated, dateModified) VALUES (" . $firstName . ", " . $lastName . ", " . $companyName . ", " . $streetAddress . ", " . $streetAddress2 . ", " . $streetAddress3 . ", " . $city . ", " . $state . ", " . $zip . ", " . $country . ", " . $phone . ", " . $fax . ", " . $email . ", NOW(), NOW())");
  mysqli_close($temp_connection);
  redirect_to('./create-user.php');
endif;
```

That query will not even push ANY data to the database, even if the field is filled out. Another way I tried the query:

```
mysqli_query($temp_connection, "INSERT INTO Address(firstName, lastName, companyName, address1, address2, address3, city, state, zip, country, phone, fax, email, dateCreated, dateModified) VALUES ('{$firstName}', '{$lastName}', '{$companyName}', '{$streetAddress}', '{$streetAddress2}', '{$streetAddress3}', '{$city}', '{$state}', '{$zip}', '{$country}', '{$phone}', '{$fax}', '{$email}', NOW(), NOW())");
```

That will return the string 'NULL' into the database if the $_POST variable is empty. I also tried to change my `sql_prep` function to this:

```
public function sql_prep($postVariable){
  $output;
  if(trim($postVariable) == ''){
    $output = NULL; //returned PhP Null instead of string 'NULL'
  }else{
  $output = strval(mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $postVariable));
  };
  return $output;
}
```

Changing it to return PhP NULL instead of 'NULL' causes the query to push just a blank column into the db.

Can't figure this one out, really want to push SQL NULL if no value.

Comment: Is your Database Field set to Default NULL ?

Comment: I believe that when you concatenate NULL into a string, it converts NULL to an empty string. Which is why you're getting "blank values" for your fields that should be set to NULL.

Comment: Yes its set to default NULL

Comment: With your first query (which is not working) you are not using any quotation marks around inserted values (you need to put them around string values) thus query is not working. In the second query you are putting quotation marks everywhere, so everything becomes a string (`NULL` as well).

Comment: Use prepared statements and forget that awful mess forever.

Comment: Rather than using `$temp_connection`, create a Connection Object for better readability and better practice (ie: `class Database { protected $Con; public function __construct() { $this->Con = new PDO(......`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), which helps you stay on the secure side as well.

```
$var = NULL;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $var);
$stmt->execute();
```

should insert a `NULL` value for you.

Comment: This is the answer I want looking for! Thank you!